# Convert list to the same format as another list in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have one matrix, matrix1 in the format I want. This matrix is dependent on two strings length. I am trying to convert matrix2 into the same format (**excluding the zeros**), but it does not work.

```
string0 = "hello"
string1 = "Good"
matrix1 = [[[0, 0] for y in range(len(string1)+1)] for x in range(len(string0)+1)]
print(matrix1) 
#output: [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
matrix2 = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

I want the matrix2 to have the same format as matrix1 and be dependent
on the strings length so I did the following:

```
tmp = [[[matrix2[i], matrix2[j]] for y in range(len(string1)+1)] for x in range(len(string0)+1)]
```

I got the wrong output, tried to remove brackets but did get an error or not the same format

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, it might not be perfect but perhaps something you can build on.

```
import itertools

def new_matrix(arr, string):
    # Create a new single array from the matrix first using itertools
    arr = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(arr))
    # Save the length of our string
    length = len(string)
    # Save the variables to a new array
    new_arr = [[]]
    # While our single array is not empty, we append the elements for the length
    # of the string to the new array at index 0 to make sure they are nested in the inner array
    # we then change the length of the array to exclude the previous iteration
    while len(arr) > 0:
        get_elems = [arr[:length]]
        new_arr[0].append(get_elems)
        arr = arr[length:]
    return new_arr
```